# Sort a sheet with protected and unprotected cells

Tags: excel, sorting, spreadsheet

I'm having a little excel trouble. I got a backlog sheet which may have some cells blocked and some others unblocked.

When I "protect the sheet" I'm leaving the user who will have access to it with the fallowing options checked:

Select locked cells
Select unlocked cells
Insert Rows
**Sort**
Use autofilter
Use pivottable reports
Edit objects
Edit scenarios

But I got complains from the user related to sorting. When they try to sort they get the fallowing message:

`The cell or chart you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only

To modify a protected cell or chart, first remove protection using the Unprotected Sheet command (Review Tab, change group). You may be prompted for a password.`

Someone nows how to handle this?

Thanks in advanced,

Pedro Dusso

Comment: You are talking about a VBA program, do you? Otherwise SO is the wrong place. Can't you just unprotect the sheet in your VBA program, sort the specific area, and protect it afterwards?

Comment: @Doc Not a straightforward problem in VBA either, because you need to figure out where your protected cells went after sorting. Some bookkeeping needed.

Comment: No, its not a VBA program. It's a spredsheet shared in a Sharepoint between business and analysts. We the dev goes for a sprint developer, we protect the cell so the business cannot alter them anymore. But the remaining cells can be update, and stay free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the user does not want protected areas to be sorted.

Some guessing: perhaps you defined the unprotected areas in a way that they cannot be sorted without interfering with the protected areas. Try to unprotect complete rows, for example, if specific rows are the part of the sheet the user wants to sort.

If that's not possible easily, because the areas in your sheet are too complex, try to add specific sort functionality written in VBA to your sheet. In VBA, you can do as I wrote in the comment above: unprotect the sheet, sort the area and protect it again.

If you need some code how to do this in VBA: the macro recorder is your friend.